# How to lower the playback sound volume on TikTok?

Tags: video, audio, tiktok

My friends suggested me to watch a TikTok video so I opened the link and the video is opened in my browser.

It was apparently muted so I wanted to unmute it, but the only thing I can see is volume icon. When I clicked it, the sound of the video was very, very loud so I tried to lower the volume but I don't know how to do it.

[image]

[image]

Can you help me where I can find the volume control in TikTok playback?

Answer (score 2):

You asked:

> ...where I can find the volume control in TikTok playback?

You canNOT.
The reason being that by default, there is no volume control in TikTok.

As an alternative though, you can install an extension/add-on to your favorite browser that will give you control over the sound of a TikTok video.

Just **[click here](https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=tiktok+volume+control)** for a Google search.

Comment: COME AGAIN??? _One of the_most popular video sites_ can't offer a volume control in a _video playback_?